# Изменить цвет *.png иконки белого цвета на любой другой цвет через css

Tags: html, css, изображения, color, png

Возможно изменить цвет *.png иконки белого цвета, на любой другой цвет (к примеру, желтый) используя css?

Рассматривал решения, где вырезают иконку и подсвечивают фоном. Но это очень странное решение для типовой задачи. Обычно такой параметр называется tintColor, но в css не нашел подобного.

Пример картинки: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B0hl.png

Comment: Уточните, что именно в png вы хотите перекрасить. Добавьте саму иконку в вопрос

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проще начинать с уже цветного изображения, но можно и с бесцветного. В этом случае нужно сначала задать базовый оттенок фильтром сепия.

```css
.make-blue {
   filter: hue-rotate(180deg) brightness(0.5) saturate(600%);
}

.make-yellow-with-sepia {
   filter: contrast(50%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(5deg) brightness(0.8) saturate(500%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGN3Z.png">

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGN3Z.png" class="make-blue">

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B0hl.png" class="make-yellow-with-sepia">
```

Директиву может потребоваться продублировать с префиксом `-webkit-`.

Comment: Это решение отлично работает. Но что делать, если нужен цвет rgba(110, 180, 172, 1.0). По какой формуле вы вычисляете параметры для filter?

Comment: Получилось, используя следующую схему: Сначала перевел rgb в hsl. Потом подставил значения в формулу hue-rotate = h - 38
    saturate = 100 + (24.5 - s)
    brightness = 100 + (l - 60.0)
    filter: brightness(50%) sepia(1)  hue-rotate(hue-rotate) 
    saturate(saturate%) brightness(brightness%);

Comment: Вопрос вычисления конкретного цвета по этой схеме заслуживает нового, отдельного, вопроса. В вашем исходном вопросе такого требования не было. Можно, кстати, самому ответить на свой вопрос.

Comment: вы правы, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо sanmai за подсказку. Чтобы перекрасить картинку в любой другой цвет, воспользовался следующей схемой:

- Перевел rgb в hsl (использовал скрипт http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/colour-handling-and-processing/)
- Подставил значения в формулу

  hue-rotate = h - 38;

  saturate = 100 + (24.5 - s);

  brightness = 100 + (l - 60.0);
- Прописал в css

`filter: brightness(50%) sepia(1)  hue-rotate(hue-rotate) 
saturate(saturate%) brightness(brightness%);`

Answer (score 1):

> Но что делать, если нужен цвет rgba(110, 180, 172, 1.0). По какой
> формуле вы вычисляете параметры для filter?

Вы можете ничего не вычислять, [но воспользоваться утилитой](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp), которая преобразует выбранный цвет в комбинацию CSS фильтров:

Например жёлтый цвет:

`filter: invert(85%) sepia(78%) saturate(6354%) hue-rotate(347deg) brightness(97%) contrast(106%);`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустим необходимо при наведении на иконку закрасить её из жёлтого в красный цвет:

```css
img:hover {
filter: invert(85%) sepia(78%) saturate(6354%) hue-rotate(347deg) brightness(97%) contrast(106%);
}
img {
filter: invert(16%) sepia(100%) saturate(6087%) hue-rotate(2deg) brightness(115%) contrast(123%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B0hl.png" class="make-yellow-with-sepia">
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно через: `filter: invert();`

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]